# Recreating the Contacts App that comes with iphone by default

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, addressbook

Im trying to recreate the contacts app for learning purpose . you can see in your iphones it has 5 tabs . and in the 3rd tab is selected the contacts are shown with a "+" bar button item. How do i implement this? using address book framework this seems not possible since it can only be presented modally , I dont want to show it modally I want it to be one of the view controller itself . 
[image] . I have a snapshot of it but I cant post it cuz I need to have 10 reputation to do so ......

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpOZp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample example as per your requirement :

https://github.com/Kadasiddha/AddressBook

Output will be as given below:

[image: AddressBook Example]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have seen this , this is not Im looking for . its presenting the ABPeoplePicker modally I dont want that .When I open the App the first thing I want to see should be like above screenshot

Comment: please explain required init im new to ios swift

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=20359 for init explanation

Comment: I have created a sample code as per your requirement.  I have given the GitHub link for the sample code.